# Garbage collection on Unmanaged COM object references

Tags: c#, com, com-interop

I am working on a project where I am referencing one COM C++ dll. The classes inside this dll are in nested form which creates a hierarchy

Example

```
 Cats-->
    Cat1-->
      --> Ears
         --> Ear1
         --> Ear2
    Cat2-->
      --> Ears
         --> Ear1
         --> Ear2
```

Cats and Ears are Collections, So In my case I am Creating object of mammals class :

```
Mammals objMammals= new Mammals();
objMammals.Cats.Add(); // Adds a cat object with default values
```

and then you can add Ears and so On and everything works fine.

But Problem occurs when you try the same thing using reflection.

```
int MammalsId = (int)objMammals.GetType().InvokeMember("FindById", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null,objMammals, new object{0});// returns the Mammals Object Id from hierarchy

object CatsObject = (object)objMammals.GetType().InvokeMember("Cats", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.GetProperty, null,objMammals, new object{1});
```

The above line works fine but once you call GC.Collect() in between the last two lines the objMammals.GetType() will turn to __ComObject(which does not have Cats) and it will start throwing runtime exceptions.

The Dll reference is Isolated and I can see the generated Manifest file looks correct. I've tried to register the Dll as well as the Interop as well but No luck, If some how I create any reference of Cats object or Ears object before the GC comes in then It works just fine.

I want the objects to always contain their actual type, So I can use the reflection as i need to.

Comment: Difficult to say w/o a reproducing code, but .NET garbage collection should not have an incidence on your code. Maybe there are issues with the C++ COM server. Note you can use C# `dynamic` keyword/type instead of reflection for COM dynamic calls.

Comment: @SimonMourier : I've already tried the dynamic keyword but it does not solve my problem, I am creating dynamic Event handlers for these objects, For that GetType() must return the actual type. It looks like when the GC kicks In it clears the underlying RCW (because it was not referenced in managed code anywhere).  If I call GC.KeepAlive for that object before GC the object lives and my code works. But I can not call GC.KeepAlive for all the objects(there will be too many).